# Ayuda con JPQL para hacer una especie de filtro con LIKE JAVA

Tags: java, java-ee, jpa, jpql

Tengo un problema. Deseo realizar una `JPQL`, y hacer una especie de filtro que me liste los tipo de mercancia que tengan similitud con el nombre que especifica el usuario.

```
@Override
public List<TblStock> findByName(String nombre) {
    TypedQuery<TblStock> q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT p FROM TblStock p where p.tipoMercancia like '%:nombre%' ", TblStock.class);
    q.setParameter("nombre", tipoMercancia);
    return q.getResultList();    
}
```

Al hacer esta consulta, me sale el siguiente error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You have attempted to set a parameter value using a name of tipoMercancia that does not exist in
>   the query string SELECT p FROM TblStock p where p.tipoMercancia like
>   '%:tipoMercancia%' .

Claramente me no me esta aceptando el parametro `nombre`, pero no sé de qué otra forma podría hacer una consulta con un `LiKE`.

Agradezco cualquier aporte, muchas gracias.

Comment: De casualidad la variable tipoMercancia no debería ser la variable nombre?

Comment: Oh, ahí fue error mío al publicar, le puse nombre para que fuera más entendible pero olvidé editarlo en el error, pero no es esto, igual muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Según la respuesta:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20080865/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-you-have-attempted-to-set-a-parameter-value

Parece que tu problema es por el `like` que lo pones desde el `query`, por lo que el `value` se queda incompleto, el espera una llave llamada `'%:tipoMercancia%'` en vez de `tipoMercancia`.

Por lo que la solución con la corrección que me mencionaste en el comentario sería:

```
@Override
public List<TblStock> findByName(String nombre) {
    TypedQuery<TblStock> q = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT p FROM TblStock p where p.tipoMercancia like :nombre ", TblStock.class);
    q.setParameter("nombre", "%"+nombre+"%");
    return q.getResultList();    
}
```

Comment: Muchísimas graciaaas, me funciono de maravilla.

Answer (score 0):

He visto que el query se puede poner con la siguiente estructura para que compare con el valor ingresado los campos que se tienen en la tabla; sería como lo siguiente:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM TblStock p where p.tipoMercancia like concat ('%', :nombre, '%' ) ")
List<TblStock> findByNombreMercancia(String nombre);
```

Esto con Springboot lo he hecho. Podrían intentar adaptar así el query.